# Trouble moving a cell reference using offset

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I'm having a little trouble trying to import data from other spreadsheets into a master spreadsheet.
I'm looking to open 16 spreadsheets, grab a block of data from each and paste it into the master spreadsheet. I'm then looking to move my cell reference 12 rows down then repeat.
It's the last part I'm having trouble with - I'm trying to use offset but it doesn't seem to move the cell. All that happens is the data is overwritten over the first.
PasteStart actually appears as a blank value on the second loop

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteStart As Range
Dim count As Integer
Dim name As String

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set PasteStart = [Sheet1!A1]

PasteStart = Application.InputBox(prompt:="ENTER a Single Cell Address to paste data or leave it blank to exit", Type:=2)

If PasteStart = "" Then
    Exit Sub
Else

For count = 1 To 16

    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (Title:="Please choose a Report to Parse", _
    FileFilter:="Report Files *.xlsx (*.xlsx),")


        If FileToOpen = False Then
            MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)

            Sheets("JourneyPlanner").Select

            PasteStart.Value = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Who's data are you inputting?", Type:=2)


            ActiveSheet.Range("B132:B139").Copy
            PasteStart.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            ActiveSheet.Range("C132:C139").Copy
            PasteStart.Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            ActiveSheet.Range("D132:D133").Copy
            PasteStart.Offset(1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            ActiveSheet.Range("E132:E133").Copy
            PasteStart.Offset(1, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If

    Row = Row + 12
    PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(12, 0)
    wb2.Close

Next count

End If

End Sub
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(12,0)` will set the value of `PasteStart` equal to that of `PasteStart.Offset(12,0)`.  You need to use the `Set` keyword to indicate that you want to assign the variable to a new range.

Try this one: `Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(12,0)`